# NSMultipleValuesMarker use of undeclared type in Swift 3

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nsarraycontroller

I'm working on a mixed Objective-C / Swift macOS app.

I'm writing some code that checks the value returned from the selection key on an arrayController. NSArrayControllers return Any and normally I would check for multiple selection by seeing if the Any is a NSMultipleValuesMarker. However, writing this in Swift 3 I get the error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'NSMultipleValuesMarker'
```

The code I'm attempting is:

```
    var selection = arrayController.value(forKeyPath: "selection.image")

    if selection is NSMultipleValuesMarker {
        // Do something for this case
    }
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing to have NSMultipleValuesMarker available. I've tried importing Foundation, Cocoa and AppKit, but none of them seem to make the error go away.

Comment: `NSMultipleValuesMarker` isn't a type or class, it's a constant.

Comment: @Willeke I've edited the question accordingly. But this still doesn't answer the question?

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Added code, as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'is' is the type check operator to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. Use `selection === NSMultipleValuesMarker` to check if `selection` is `NSMultipleValuesMarker`.